# If $ \int_{0}^{b}f(x) \; dx =0$ then $ \int_{0}^{b}f(x+y_0) \; dx =0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and periodic function, with period $b>0$. Let $ y_0 \in [0,b]$ be a fixed number.

**Question.** If
$$\frac{1}{b}\int_{0}^{b}f(x) \; dx =0 \tag{1}$$
then
$$\int_{0}^{b}f(x+y_0) \; dx =0 \tag{2}?$$

In order to prove $(2)$ I thought: making a variable change $z=x+y_0$ in $(2)$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{b}f(x+y_0) \; dx&=&\int_{y_0}^{b+y_0}f(z) \; dx =\int_{y_0}^{b}f(z) \; dx+\int_{b}^{b+y_0}f(z) \; dx \\
&=& \int_{0}^{b}f(z) \; dx+ \int_{y_0}^{b}f(z) \; dx+ \int_{b}^{y_0}f(z) \; dx+ \int_{y_0}^{y_0}f(z) \; dx \\
&=&\int_{y_0}^{b}f(z) \; dx+ \int_{b}^{y_0}f(z) \; dx= \int_{y_0}^{y_0}f(z) \; dx=0.
\end{eqnarray}

Is this right? Moreover, I think that this holds for any $y_0>0$.

Comment: you are right and it does hold for any $y_0>0$

Comment: Put your coment as a answer, please.

Comment: Ah you did put one end of your integral wrong. Nevertheless, if you can change, it would okay.

Comment: Which one integral?

Comment: in the first line, the last one, I should be $ \int_{b}^{b+y_0}$ . Then the second line of yours is a bit obscure but I guess its okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Alternatively, you could write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^bf(x+y_0)dx&=\int_{y_0}^{y_0+b}f(z)dz\\
&=\int_{y_0}^{y_0+b}f(z)dz\\
&=\int_{y_0}^bf(z)dz+\int_{b}^{y_0+b}f(z)dz\\
&=\int_{y_0}^bf(z)dz+\int_{0}^{y_0}f(z)dz\\
&=\int_{0}^bf(z)dz\\
&=0.
\end{align}$$